# How can I disable a checkbox with a specific class?

Tags: jquery

Hello I am disabling all checkboxes which are not checked.

```
$(":checkbox:not(:checked)").prop('disabled', true)
```

My problem is that I do not know how to select only the checkboxes with the class `checkbox`. I tried to do it like this:

```
$(".checkbox:checkbox:not(:checked)").prop('disabled', true)
```

Comment: Using `[type='checkbox']` is a lot more efficient than using `:checkbox`. See [here](https://jsperf.com/type-vs-colon-selector).

Comment: see my answer may be it will help you to select using class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this way:

```
$("input.checkbox:checkbox:not(:checked)")
```

Comment: How will this function any differently? Since `:checkbox` will only target `type=checkbox` elements.

Comment: @George Yes, that's the question: *select only the checkboxes*. And it works. Confirmed by the OP in his next comment.

Comment: Working very well! Thank you :)

Comment: The code in the question will already *select only the checkboxes*, no?

Comment: It works as said by the OP. Problem solved @George! `:)` Cool.

Comment: @George Yes, but I have checkboxes with a different class which I do not want to disable

Comment: @Jarla see my answer you will find your solution it will disabled only checkbox class

Answer (score 2):

See this examle http://jsfiddle.net/uwsy2xuv/1/

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" checked>
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
```

jquery

```
console.log($("input[type='checkbox']"))  //selector for all checkbox.
console.log($("input[type='checkbox'].checkbox")) //selector for all checkbox which has class checkbox.



$("input[type='checkbox'].checkbox:not(:checked)").prop('disabled', true)
OR
$("input:checkbox.checkbox:not(:checked)").prop('disabled', true)
```

Comment: By the way, `input.checkbox:checkbox` translates to `input[type='checkbox'].checkbox`. Oh yeah, only a true developer will know. How will you know! `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar   <i> is used to print code for answer in stackoverflow and this statement is given by stackoverflow  maybe you can understand.  see this image  http://imgur.com/rLIJDdK

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that this is misleading the new users. It just says you need to indent the code. Sorry for being ultimately rude.

Comment: Also, bro, it says since `<i>` is a HTML tag and Markdown supports HTML and if you wanna show the `<i>` as a code and not convert it as HTML, they have given that. Do you understand?